# Chevrons in live captions being sanitized to &gt;

Tags: youtube-api

The company I work for makes a software for, among other things, providing real time captions which includes YouTube live event captions.

We're running into an issue where chevrons are being sanitized to `&gt;`in the process of being handed to YouTube and displayed on the stream. We're assuming YouTube is looking to receive some other string or code to properly display chevrons in the captions, but I can't seem to find any information along those lines in the documentation we have.

If anyone has any insight as to what we can do to get chevrons to display properly, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please be more specific with your question? Please provide more information about what YouTube API Captions method you call (insert/list/update...), what programming language you use and include some relevant source code responsible for calling the API method.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the programmer for this software and don't have the answer to those questions. I'll have to get in touch with him and get the answers for those.

Comment: Please do that. The chances to get a good answer are quite low now because it's hard to figure out what kind of encoding problem you face with your software.